# Xamarin Como - Como Ejecutar methodo en ViewModel desde la View

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm, viewmodel

Hola estoy usando **Xamarin Forms Mvvm** y en mi view model tengo un methodo que me gustaria llamar cuando mi vista se cree, Alguien sabe la forma correcta de hacer esto? Entonces lo que tengo es lo siguiente:

```
 public partial class StudentsPage : ContentPage
{
    public StudentsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new StudentsViewModel
        (
            RestService.For<IJMServices>("https://miappi.herokuapp.com")
        );
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();             
    }

}
```

y este es mi view model donde quiero ejecutar **LoadStudents**

```
public class StudentsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _id;

    public string Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Id");
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<StudentData> students { get; set; }
    private IJMServices _iJMService { get; set; }

    public StudentsViewModel(IJMServices JMServices)
    {


        Id = Preferences.Get("Id", string.Empty);
        _iJMService = JMServices;
        students = new ObservableCollection<StudentData>();
        // _ = LoadStudents();

    }

    private async Task LoadStudents()
    {
        UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading();
        var st = await _iJMService.GetStudents(Id);
        students.Clear();

        foreach (StudentData s in st)
        {
            students.Add(s);
        }

        UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Tenes algun problema con ese metodo? yo lo suelo hacer de esa forma tambien.

Answer (score 0):

A ver, tu método `LoadStudents` es `async`, por lo tanto, si quieres mantenerlo así, debes declarar `OnAppearing` como método asíncrono y entonces llamar al BindingContext directo desde la vista con `this.`, así:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();    
    StudentsViewModel vm = (StudentsViewModel)this.BindingContext;
    vm.LoadStudents(); 
}
```

Y `LoadStudents` debes dejarlo como `public`, puedes simplificar el código si quieres así:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();    
    ((StudentsViewModel)this.BindingContext).LoadStudents();
}
```

Espero te ayude.

Comment: con el OnAppearing le va a volver a cargar los datos cuando vuelva a esa pantalla y quizás no necesita hacer eso.

Comment: Si no quiere una recarga puede hacerlo directamente en el constructor, o tener una variable global de tipo bool que pueda usar para comprobar si ya se realizó la carga o no, o lo que es más lógico, verificar si el el array está vacío o ya tiene elementos cargados previamente..  no mencionó nada sobre eso, sería bueno que lo agregue así le damos una mejor respuesta.